Изменение атрибута src у элемента embed при помощи JS
Делаю простенький сайт с возможностью запуска флеш-игр и смены активной игры по нажатию кнопок. По какой-то причине попытка сменить атрибут src не работает, каким образом можно это решить? Часть кода HTML:
    <div id="leftside">
        <ul>
            <li><button id="G1">G1</button></li>
            <li><button id="G2">G2</button></li>
            <li><button id="G3">G3</button></li>
            <li><button id="G4">G4</button></li>
            <li><button id="G5">G5</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <embed src="/flash/bowman.swf" id="flash">
    </div>

JS:
const flash = document.querySelector("#flash");

const BG1 = document.querySelector("#G1");
const BG2 = document.querySelector("#G2");
const BG3 = document.querySelector("#G3");
const BG4 = document.querySelector("#G4");
const BG5 = document.querySelector("#G5");

function G(p){
    flash.src = p;
}

BG1.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    G("/flash/bowman.swf");
})

BG2.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    G("/flash/the-last-stand-269.swf");
})

Так-же пытался изменить атрибут через setAttribute, но результат не изменился.

Удаляй тег целиком и добавляй новый с новыми значениями атрибута src...

Попробуйте удалить слеш вначале путей к файлам swf. А что пишет консоль?

элемент  не поддерживает изменение атрибута src напрямую через JavaScript. Вместо изменения атрибута src, можно удалить элемент  и создать его заново с новым значением src
